# не обтекается блок

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image: Вот как надо]Зеленый блок с желтыми должны обтекать красный.Мне нужно что бы было с flexbox.Но вот не знаю как сделать обтекание [image]

```css
.main-container{
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
main{
  width: 70%;
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap; 
}
.news-item{
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background: yellow;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
aside{
  width: 30%;
  background: red;

}
```

```html
<div class="container main-container">
    <main>
      <div class="news-item"></div>
      <div class="news-item"></div>
      <div class="news-item"></div>
      <div class="news-item"></div>
      <div class="news-item"></div>
      <div class="news-item"></div>
      <div class="news-item"></div>
      <div class="news-item"></div>
      <div class="news-item"></div>
      <div class="news-item"></div>
    </main>
    <aside>

    </aside>
  </div>
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно, добавьте  скрин результат который вам нужен

Comment: @E_K ДОБАВИЛ   картинку

Comment: Разве flexbox умеет делать обтекание? Используй float и не компасируй людям мозги